# Geolocation in Spring

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I have a problem trying to get the currentLat(latitude) and currentLong(longitude) in the request param instead of the default value.If I take off the default values it says it does not exist. I know the values exist because it shows up in the console when I print it.

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    GroupRepository repo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Home(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "") String day,@RequestParam(defaultValue = "35.7754742") double currentLat, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "-78.6401854") double currentLong) {
        model.addAttribute("day", day);
        model.addAttribute("groups", repo.quickFind(LocalDateTime.now().getDayOfWeek().toString(),currentLat,currentLong));
        model.addAttribute("groupsMonday", repo.listGroups("Monday",currentLat,currentLong));
        model.addAttribute("groupsTuesday", repo.listGroups("Tuesday",currentLat,currentLong));
        model.addAttribute("groupsWednesday", repo.listGroups("Wednesday",currentLat,currentLong));
        model.addAttribute("groupsThursday", repo.listGroups("Thursday",currentLat,currentLong));
        model.addAttribute("groupsFriday", repo.listGroups("Friday",currentLat,currentLong));
        model.addAttribute("groupsSaturday", repo.listGroups("Saturday",currentLat,currentLong));
        model.addAttribute("groupsSunday", repo.listGroups("Sunday",currentLat,currentLong));
        System.out.println(currentLat+" "+currentLong);
        return "index";
    }
```

Here is my javascript to get the latitude and longitude:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lat;
    var longt;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        longt = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log(lat+" "+longt);
        $.get("/?currentLat=" + lat + "&currentLong=" + longt, function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        })

    }
});
```

Comment: what about if you simplify the test and call (using browser maybe) the url with all parameters passed in?

Comment: It seems to work if I pass in the values manually via url. like: /?currentLat=56&currentLong=67

Comment: how about with double values?

Comment: double values also work.

Comment: so looks like trouble with JS.  Try reducing the scope of `lat` and `longt`

Comment: Tried moving the variables within the function. Still the same result.

Comment: make sure you have allowed your browser to access your location, not blocked.

Comment: I have allowed current location access in the browser.

Comment: Does changing `double` to `java.lang.Double` help?

Comment: unfortunately no.

Comment: @RJC, this works for me. See [this sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/44192253) on Github. Launch it as `mvn tomcat7:run` and then access the home page as `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: I would suggest looking in the browser's debug tools. Specifically, look at the network pane and see if you see your get request being sent with the correct URL params.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "If I take off the default values it says it does not exist." What is the "it" that is saying "it" doesn't exist?

Comment: The "it" is the values(lat and longt) that I get using the javascript. Oddly when spring boots, the default value shows first then the correct geolocation values show up next after a second or two.